# How to check a Value in Column or not

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a task that need to check whether a value in a cell of spreadsheet A in a column of spreadsheet B or not . After getting values of the column I have :

```
    function test() {
a = [['sđt'], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
b = [9.27915789E8];
Logger.log(b in a)

}
```

Output : FALSE

what can I do to make it TRUE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test() {
  const a = [['sđt'], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [9.27915789E8], [6.5762895E8], [8.8543159E8], [6.48624091E8], [9.43630775E8], [6.45340742E8], [8.90007311E8], [6.1349516E8], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []].filter(e => e[0]).filter((e, i) => i > 0).flat();
  const b = [9.27915789E8];
  Logger.log(a.includes(b[0]));
}
```

[includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Thank you , it works , but can you explain in detail so I can understand to solve it next time

Comment: I provide some references.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether any element in an array matches a condition, use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const elementIsThere = a.some(value => value[0] === b[0]);
console.log(elementIsThere);
```